# Add Comma If Next Field Is Not Null

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2000

I need to display data in a lastname, firstname, salutation format.  However there are a few rare instances where salutation is null, so I wouldn't want to display firstname, if salutation is null.  Or there (doubtful) could be a possibility that firstname is null and salutation so I wouldn't want to show lastname, , ,.

**How can I in my query use a condition to only include the comma if the next field is not null?**

```
NameWithSal: [LastName] + ", " + [FirstName] + ", " + [Salutation]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Access, what you have will result in null if any of the fields are null. The following should provide what you specified.  [LastName] & ", " + [FirstName] & ", " + [Salutation]

Comment: So the comma will not be added if the field is null?

Comment: Hi AVG, it would be good to mention that you only get null if you use + to concatenate, & does not do this.